# how to show multiple image getting from xml

Tags: iphone, xml, image, imageview

i've this problem i'm looking for a way to create an a UIImageView which shows photos that are taking from my web server ( using the xml in order to do automatically ) 
my purpose is to create an imageView like Fancy app

Answer (score 0):

A very good description has been given through [Asynchronous UIImage from web](http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2009/10/asynchronous-uiimage-from-web.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to be able to display multiple UIImageViews. You can create a `UIScrollView` and use it as a container, so you can have any (reasonable) number of images. Then use a loop to create a frame, a `UIImageView` and any other configuration for your images, add the image as a subview to the scroll view and change the `UIScrollView`'s `contentSize` to allow scrolling.

something along the lines of:

```
    CGRect baseFrame = CGRectMake(kXOffset, xYOffset, kImageSize, kImageSize); 
    int count = [myArray count]; // myArray contains your data
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *unit = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect buttonFrame = baseFrame;
        buttonFrame.origin.y += (kImageSize + kSpacing) * (i / 3);

        // "imageName" below is a sample key for your image name, you can change this with url or whatever
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[unit objectForKey:@"imageName"]]]; 
        [img setFrame:buttonFrame];
        [myScrollView addSubview:img];
        [img release]; // if not using ARC
    }
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 20 + (kImageSize + 2 * kSpacing) * ([army count] / 3))]; // some air above and below
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming you have the XML parsed already or at least know how to do so. If you don't know where to start, begin looking at NSXMLParser. You can find plenty of tutorials/resolved questions concerning it with a quick google search.

For the images, I would recommend the SDWebImage library available [here](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It can be a pain to get the library imported but the process is given in the ReadMe, and I have found this library to be incredibly useful/versatile. The ReadMe also details how to use the code, which is actually very simple and intuitive. I can provide my own code sample if you'd like and answer any questions concerning importing the library.

Regarding the layout, Alexander has given what I believe to be a good starting point, at the very least, in his answer.